# knife-ec2 not expanding volume at bootstrap

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, knife, ec2-ami

How can I create a larger than 8GB boot partition volume using knife-ec2 on an AWS hvm ami at boostrap?

In the old instance type of m1, i could just add --ebs-size 50 then run resize2fs after the system boot strapped.

When doing a new hvm ami (a t2 instance):

```
knife ec2 server create scott-base -N scott-base -r "role[base]" -I ami-57cfc412 --ebs-size 50
```

it will create the 50GB volume, but i cannot expand it after I login.
I see this during the build:

```
Warning: 50GB EBS volume size is larger than size set in AMI of 8GB.
Use file system tools to make use of the increased volume size.
```

And when I run resize2fs, this is what I get

```
[root@scott-base ~ ] resize2fs /dev/xvda
resize2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
resize2fs: Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/xvda
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock
```

I know I can go through the whole process of unmounting, copying and bringing it back up.  I also know i can just add a volume after the fact, but I have to believe there is an easier way at bootstrap to get a larger ebs volume than 8GB.

```
[root@scott-base ~]# lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0  50G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 part /
```

Comment: please include `lsblk` output

Comment: [root@scott-base ~]# lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0  50G  0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 part /

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to apply [`resize2fs`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/resize2fs) command to device reference `/dev/xvda` which is not file system itself, you can divide devices into partions, where you create file system (ext3,ext4,etc). You do have partition with filesystem on `/dev/xvda1` partion, where you want to use `resize2fs`. Please read the [documentation about devices and partions in linux](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition/devices.html).

Answer (score 0):

The solution was related to the AMI itself. It turns out that some ami's are just not equipped with the ability to expand online.  Our solution:

1. Launch the ami with a larger partition, knowing it would only default 8GB
2. Use the cloud-init and dracut module to increase the size during the next reboot

   ```
   yum install -y cloud-init
   yum install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
   yum install -y dracut-modules-growroot.noarch cloud-utils-growpart
   dracut -f -v
   ```
3. Create a a personal image from that instance
4. Use the personal image to launch a new instance.  At boot, it will be the larger size